# Java string not equals

Tags: java, string, equals

So I have String array

```
String[] faculties = new String[21];
```

and I need to fill it with the names of faculties from .txt file that looks like

> Math & CS; First Speciality; First Program; etc
>
> Math & CS; Second Speciality; First Program; etc
>
> Math & CS; Second Speciality; Second Program; etc
>
> Physics; First Speciality; First Program; etc
>
> Physics; First Speciality; Second Program; etc

I use the next code to get these names

```
FileReader input = new FileReader("faculties1.txt");
BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
String myLine;
int f = 0;

    while((myLine = bufRead.readLine())!= null){
        String[] arr = myLine.split(";");

        if(f == 0){
            faculties[f] = arr[0];
            f++;
        }
        else{
            if(!faculties[f-1].trim().equals(arr[0].trim())){
                faculties[f] = arr[0];
                f++;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I try to check my array

```
for(int i = 0; i < f; i++){
        System.out.println(faculties[i]);
    }
```

console says me

> ﻿Math & CS
>
> Math & CS
>
> Physics

I dont get why Java puts "Math & CS" second time to my array.

Comment: Did you try to step  through it with a debugger?

Comment: @litelite yep. this `if(!faculties[f-1].trim().equals(arr[0].trim()))` returns `true` when `f == 1` even if `arr[0] == "Math & CS"` and `faculties[f-1] == "Math & CS"`

Comment: Maybe some kind of invisible unicode caracter somewhere in the file? You can try to open the file with something like notepad++ or sublime text and activate the show all caracters option.

Comment: Try doing a String.compare on `faculties[f-1]` and `arr[0]`? If that returns anything other than 0, there's a character issue, as @litelite says

Comment: @litelite thank you much! I used UTF-8 .txt in my project to see cyrillic symbols in console, but when I changed .txt to ANSI console said me `Math & CS Physics`

Comment: It's problem with your "newLine" blank line, see in your file. After one line statement are blank line and again statement.
Try to save it below in file or handle blank line in your code.
Math & CS; First Speciality; First Program; etc
Math & CS; Second Speciality; First Program; etc
Math & CS; Second Speciality; Second Program; etc
Physics; First Speciality; First Program; etc
Physics; First Speciality; Second Program; etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this it is worked fine and output returns as you expected I think, anyhow you need to throws exceptions.

```
Math & CS
Physics
```

According to me there can be,

mispelled character in your text file. Check using different text-editor rather than windows notepad.

**UPDATE:**

After added this answer I saw **your last comment** in question that your problem solved.

I am adding this comment because if someone did not see your comment this will be helpful to them.

> I **used UTF-8 .txt** in my project to see cyrillic symbols in console, but **when I changed .txt to ANSII** console said me Math & CS Physics*

Comment: Affter added this answer I saw your last comment in question that your problem solved.